# Empty left join only in production

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a website running on symfony2.

I have this dql query :

```
SELECT b, d, al, a 
FROM Bundle:Book b  
LEFT JOIN b.document d
LEFT JOIN b.authorLinks al
LEFT JOIN al.author a    
WHERE d.type = 'summary'
ORDER BY b.name ASC
```

Locally I don't have any issues but in production I have this issue :

```
... LEFT JOIN LEFT JOIN ...
```

So the first LEFT JOIN (b.document d) don't work in production but well locally... (the others LEFT JOIN (authorLinks & author) works both)

My `Book` entity has :

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Document", mappedBy="book")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $document;
```

My `Document` entity has :

```
/**
 * @var Book
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="document")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
protected $book;
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: did you clear your production cache? what is your caching engine? Basically entities relation might be cached so you need to clear it. Depending on your caching engine something like restart of apache will help

Comment: yes I did cache:clear --env=prod

Comment: As I heard, I don't need on clauses because the relations are already configured

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is DQL, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

I added "with d.book_id = b.id" after "LEFT JOIN b.document d"

And added

```
/**
 * @var book_id
 * @ORM\Column(name="book_id", type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
protected $book_id;
```

In the Document entity

thx for all !